# setState not updating the data on previous page

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, setstate

I made a language switcher and rendered a button on every page. I went to 2nd page from 1st page which is in english and switched the language to arabic on 2nd page using setState. But when I came back to 1st page, the language was still english on 1st page even though I used a global variable called "lang" which is integer and executed setState on 2nd page. I have multiple dart files in my project so is there any work around that can set the state of all the previous pages in navigator?

Comment: Can you include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think its better to use state managements in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global variables, state management is better options. You can also use `ValueNotifier` with `ValueListenableBuilder`.

```dart
final ValueNotifier<bool> isArabic = ValueNotifier(false);
```

And use `ValueListenableBuilder` like

```dart
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: isArabic,
  builder: (BuildContext context, dynamic value, Widget? child) {
    return Scaffold();
  },
),
```

And  change value like

```dart
 isArabic.value = false;
```

More about [`ValueNotifier`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueNotifier-class.html) and  [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html).